# MouseRotate using Java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I am using `MouseRotate` class of java 3d, and I am using it to rotate two cylinders. But the problem is when I rotate one cylinder the other cylinder rotates with it. Is there a way around this or do I have to do it differently?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the code. So could you please show some code?

Comment: crossposted http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/375587

Comment: This is the code that i am working on. There are two cylinders each with a transform group called rotationGroup. i am using Mouserotate to rotate the two cylinders.           MouseRotate myMouseRotate = new MouseRotate();
   myMouseRotate.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
    myMouseRotate.setFactor(0, 0.1);
    myMouseRotate.setTransformGroup(rotationXform);
                  rotationgroup.addChild(myMouseRotate);

Answer (score 0):

after short look into the MouseRotate API I guess the following steps are necessary

- create 2 instances of MouseRotate using the constructor with the TransformGroup. One with the TransformGroup of each cylinder
- now you need to implement a selection for the cylinder to be rotated, either by clicking them or by pressing a button (e.g. button 1 for the first, 2 for the second). After one cylinder is selected the according MouseRotate should be used and the other deactivated

Comment: That can be done but the problem is wherever i rotate the mouse on the Canvas, the cylinder rotates. Is there a way to deactivate that, since the cylinder is rotating irrespective of whether the mouse is on it or not.

Comment: I am not familiar with Java3D but if you are able to switch between the two cylinders it should also be possible to deselect both. In the most dirty way you could create an invisible object an rotate this. A better way would be to deactivate MouseRotate if no one should be transformed.